# Get the compilation fast again

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I used [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) to generate a C# file which has nearly 1 million lines of code. Even though it never changes, it slowed down the compilation process of the whole project. Is there a possibility to get it fast again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put the auto generated file in a project of its own. Compile it to an assembly and add a reference to that assembly from the project you want to make fast. This way you don't have to recompile the auto generated file more than once.